# Polynomial question with remainders

Tags: polynomials

I have a problem that I cannot solve, the problem is as follows:

> Find a polynomial with the lowest power $p(x)$ such that its remainder by dividing it with $(x-1)^2$ is $2x$, and the remainder by dividing it by $(x-2)^3$ is $3x$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your attempts, please.

Comment: @Mathology  Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. What are your thoughts on this problem? Generally questions showing no effort by the person asking, don't get a lot of answers.

Comment: Oh okay. Well I have tried setting the equations and switching x=1 and x=2, but I get stuck there. I get that p(1)=2 and p(2)=6 but I don't know how to finish the problem.

Comment: @Mathology Please write the equations so we can see where you are stuck.

Comment: @Mathology: your approach doesn't account power in $(x-1)^2$ and $(x-2)^3$. According to polynomial division remainder definition $p(x)=a(x) (x-2)^3 +3x$. From problem statement follows that $a(x)$ must have lower possible power. Start with $a(x)=a_0$ and check if it is consistent with remainder $2x$ from dividing by $(x-1)^2$.

Comment: p(x)=a(x)(x−2)^3+3x, and p(x)=b(x)(x−1)^2+2x are the equations.

Comment: I found it easier to solve by replacing $x-2$ with $t$.